# How do inactivate Brave Shields in a Selenium script?

Tags: python, selenium, brave-browser

I want to access websites including their ads with Selenium in my brave browser. But Brave has a built in adblocker (Brave Shields), which prevent Selenium from seeing ads. How can I start brave without Brave Shields?
Is there some options-argument, that I can pass to selenium, like options.add_argument("--no-adblock")?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late to add an answer but it might help someone in the future. This worked for me, hope it works for anyone out there.

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = 'path to brave browser binary'
options.add_argument('--disable-brave-extension')  # this will disable brave browser shields
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
```